# Time Machine backup taking longer over Ethernet than Wifi?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, time-machine

I just purchased a Synology DS412J NAS. I installed 2 3TiB drives in it and formated it as SHR1.

I have a fileshare setup to store my Time Machine backups.

I started a fresh TM backup on my Mac Mini (latest gen, Core i5, 16GB RAM, 128 SSD) which is attached via gigabit Ethernet to the NAS through my cable modem which is also gigabit ethernet. This backup is crawling.

While it was running, I started a fresh TM Backup on my MacBook Air(latest gen i5, 4GB, 128 SSD) to the same NAS, to rule out a problem with the NAS. It worked fine.

It backedup 29.8 Gigabytes of data  in less time than it has taken the Mac Mini to backup 7.

I checked the Network Utilization monitor on the NAS and can confirm that the Mac Mini is sending data at a much slower rate than the MBA.

Comment: Have you tried changing the cables?

Comment: @Ramhound That was the problem, this morning i was digging and found that it was only connecting at 10BaseT speed.

Comment: **Always check if the television is plugged in :-)**

Comment: Yeah, I've owned hundreds of Ethernet cables never had one go bad until now. guess i took it for granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cable between the mini and router was bad.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer